# How to save file from S3 using aws-sdk v3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

With the new aws-sdk v3, specifically `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, it's not clear to me how to store files to disk from S3.
Having the following code

```js
const { Body } = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({
  Bucket: 'myBucket',
  Key: 'myKey',
}))
```

The `Body` can be of type `Readable | ReadableStream | Blob`.
I'd like to store this into a file on disk. Since the return types are completely different, is there an easy way to e.g. get a `Buffer` or `Stream.Readable` from aws-sdk?

In aws-sdk v2 it was easy with `.createReadStream()` function which seems to no longer exist.

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1096#issuecomment-620900466

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears `ReadableStream | Blob` is [available only in browser](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-776187712). Node.js always gets `Readable` which is what I need.

The solution is pretty straightforward afterwards with `fs.createWriteStream` and piping the `Readable` such as

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
    .on('error', err => reject(err))
    .on('close', () => resolve())
})
```

For reference, here's an issue where improvement to documentation is discussed https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877

Comment: If you're using Typescript - see the enhancement from Abigail Nguyen below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the streaming methods, as mentioned in the responses above, but you can also just use the `writeFile` method from the `fs/promises` library:

```
const { writeFile } = require("node:fs/promises");
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const downloadFile = async () => {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key });
    const { Body } = await client.send(command);

    const localFilename = "path_to_where_to_save_file";

    await writeFile(localFilename, Body);
}
```

and then call this function.

I think this is from node version [v14.18.0](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options) onwards, because this method accepts a stream as input.

Comment: Best answer in my opinion when using modern Node.js

Answer (score 4):

To do this in typescript you can also do

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 if (Body instanceof Readable) {
   Body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
    .on('error', err => reject(err))
    .on('close', () => resolve())
 }
});
```

Comment: Note that you may have to ```import { Readable } from 'stream'```

Answer (score 2):

GetObjectCommand returns readable stream, we use fs module to create writeStream and pass the returned readableStream from GetObjectCommand to writeStream to save the file

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: 'your_region',
  credentials: { accessKeyId: 'your_accessKeyId', secretAccessKey: 'your_secretAccessKey' },
});

const bucketParams = {
  Bucket: 'your_bucket',
  Key: 'your_key.jpg',
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams));
    const inputStream = data.Body;
    const downloadPath = 'example.png';
    const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath);
    inputStream.pipe(outputStream);
    outputStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log(`downloaded the file successfully`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
};
```