# Is posible get an Object from AWS S3 in Blob format with AWS SDK for JavaScript V3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, blob

I am in a project with Next.js and I need upload photos to a Bucket S3, I want to use the last in tech, so I am using the [SDK for JavaScript in the last version (3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html)

All fine for now, I have uploaded my first photo to my bucket after a lot struggles, but when I am gonna see the image I have get this error:

[image]

My goal is get the URL for set my `src` in `<img />` element, this seems a permission problem with my bucket but my question is: Is possible use the [GetObjectCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html) for get the resource with the key and save in a Blob object, for after use `URL.createObjectURL` and link the image in my HTML?

I have tried this:

```
const BUCKET = 'bucket'

const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'accessKey',
        secretAccessKey: 'secretKey'
    }
})

const response = await client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: 'folder/image.jpg'
}))
```

But the `response.Body` variable is of type `ReadableStream` not a `Blob`

After search in Internet how to convert the `ReadableStream` to `Blob` nothing has worked for me, because maybe all the approaches I have see, it speaks about **download** the resource (to the machine), like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689614/how-to-save-file-from-s3-using-aws-sdk-v3) in Node.js

I am not expert in JavaScript but is possible I am ignoring some concepts about streams and blobs, sorry for that.

As you can see I want to access in a secure way to the resource without make public my bucket (because I want to use the same bucket for save private files with a different key), is my approach bad? is possible get this or how to solve in a better way my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting to provide public access to selective objects.

This can be done in two ways:

- If an object should be permanently 'public', then you can specify `ACL=public-read` when uploading the object to S3
- If you wish to keep objects fully private, but selectively make an object accessible via URL then you can use an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object -- basically, your back-end code generates the URL and inserts it into the HTML (`<img src="..." />`)

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot, but i have another question, in the first option I have tried with the `ACL=public-read` but I got the `The bucket does not allow ACLs` error, do you know what this mean and how to enable it?

Comment: Nevermind I have solve it in the AWS Dashboard, activating the ACL for my bucket :) now I can upload public resources with the flag `ACL: 'public-read'` if I need, otherwise will be private access, thanks!